# Creating a function in compile time using a bitmap like macro

Tags: c, macros

I have an ansi C function to sum up values from an array, based on patterns. Something like:

```
long sum_all_according_to_pattern(int n, int *values, int *pattern)
{
    long sum = 0;
    int i = 0;
    for(;i<n;i++){
        if(pattern[i])
            sum+=values[i];
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Let's say I've a set of patterns such as:

Pattern 1: 1,1,1,1

Pattern 2: 1,1,0,0

Pattern 3: 1,0,0,1

I need to generate a specific code for each pattern, without the loop and the if. For the previous patterns, it would be:

```
long sum_according_to_pattern_1(int *values)
{
    return values[0]+values[1]+values[2]+values[3];
}

long sum_according_to_pattern_2(int *values)
{
    return values[0]+values[1];
}

long sum_according_to_pattern_3(int *values)
{
    return values[0]+values[3];
}
```

or even

```
long sum_according_to_pattern_1(int *values)
{
    long sum = 0;
    sum+=values[0];
    sum+=values[1];
    sum+=values[2];
    sum+=values[3];
    return sum;
}

long sum_according_to_pattern_2(int *values)
{
    long sum = 0;
    sum+=values[0];
    sum+=values[1];
    return sum;
}

long sum_according_to_pattern_3(int *values)
{
    long sum = 0;
    sum+=values[0];
    sum+=values[3];
    return sum;
}
```

Now, suppose that such patterns can be much larger than only 4 elements. Also, suppose I've much more than only these 3 patterns.

My question is: there is some way to achieve that using only ansi C constructions? As I'm trying to keep everything contained, I don't want to write a script to generate the code for me. What I need is to specify the pattern using something like a bitmap macro and than generate the function during compile time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way I would do it would be with a macro that defined all the patterns you want, combined with other macros that defined the functions or other info you need about them.  So you would have something like:

```
#define FUNCTION_PATTERNS(M) \
    M(1, 0xf) \
    M(2, 0x3) \
    M(3, 0x9)

#define DEFINE_SUM_FUNCTION(NUM, PATTERN) \
long sum_according_to_pattern_##NUM(int *values) {   \
    long sum = 0;                                    \
    for (int i = 0; 1UL << i <= PATTERN; i++)        \
        if (PATTERN & (1UL << i)) sum += values[i];  \
}

#define SUM_FUNCTION_NAME(NUM, PATTERN) sum_according_to_pattern_##NUM
```

now you can easily declare all the functions and build a table of pointers to them:

```
FUNCTION_PATTERNS(DEFINE_SUM_FUNCTION)

long (*sum_functions[])(int *) = { FUNCTION_PATTERNS(SUM_FUNCTION_NAME) };
```

if you want, you can manually unroll the loop in the `DEFINE_SUM_FUNCTION` macro, or you can rely on your C compiler to do it for you, possibly with an appropriate pragma or compile-time flag.

Note that the above will only work up to 32 or 64 elements (depending on architecture).  If you want more, you'll have to split the patterns into multiple values.

Comment: In the code you provided, after the macro expanded, the compiler will get rid of the conditional testing of the pattern?

Comment: If it unrolls the loop, which most compilers will do when optimizations are enabled, the compiler will evaluate all the ifs at compile time.  If you care, you should check the optimization options available for your compiler and see what they do.

Answer (score 0):

Extending Chris Dodd's approach.

I think you can generate exactly what you describe by using a list of symbols for the patterns. So, starting with the same X-macro setup.

```
#define PATTERNS(_) \
_(1, A B C D) \
_(2, A B) \
_(3, A D) \
/**/

#define A sum += values[0];
#define B sum += values[1];
#define C sum += values[2];
#define D sum += values[3];
#define GEN_FUNC(num, pattern) \
long sum_accoring_to_pattern ## num (int *values) { \
    long sum = 0; \
    pattern \
    return sum; \
}

PATTERNS(GEN_FUNC)
```

Running through `cpp -P genpat.c | indent -gnu -i4 -br -ce -cdw -nbc -brf -brs -l100 -bbo` yields

```
long
sum_accoring_to_pattern1 (int *values) {
    long sum = 0;
    sum += values[0];
    sum += values[1];
    sum += values[2];
    sum += values[3];
    return sum;
}

long
sum_accoring_to_pattern2 (int *values) {
    long sum = 0;
    sum += values[0];
    sum += values[1];
    return sum;
}

long
sum_accoring_to_pattern3 (int *values) {
    long sum = 0;
    sum += values[0];
    sum += values[3];
    return sum;
}
```

You could also generate the shorter form.

```
#define PATTERNS(_) \
_(1, A B C D) \
_(2, A B) \
_(3, A D) \
/**/

#define A + values[0]
#define B + values[1]
#define C + values[2]
#define D + values[3]
#define GEN_FUNC(num, pattern) \
long sum_accoring_to_pattern ## num (int *values) { \
    return pattern ;\
}

PATTERNS(GEN_FUNC)
```

You almost certainly want to `#undef` `A` .. `D` afterword. :)